# a command to list share folders in my network?

Tags: command-line

I am a new Ubuntu user , i have a question about commands in Terminal .

Is there a command that **list all shared directories** in my network ?

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use smbclient by entering this code :

```
smbclient -L hostname
```

Where hostname is the ip of the Pc you want to see its shared filed